# How to add additional foreign properties to table?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first

I'm using Entity Framework 6 with Code First.

Basically, my database has a **Movie** and an **Image** table with a one-to-many relation (Movie has the foreign key: **Image_Id**).

**Image** has a column named **Url**.

When I wish to display a list of movies, I'd like to display the image URL's along with them. Right now I am forced to access the image table itself, eg.:

```
string imageUrl = movie.Image.Url;
```

Which seems like an unnecessary join.

How do I include the **Url** column as a foreign property on **Movie** so that I can access it without loading the image (sort of like **Image_Id**).

Comment: If you don't want join, write this: `var url = db.Images.Where(x => x.Id == movie.Image_Id).FirstOrDefault()?.Url`

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options.  Option 1 is to de-normalize your database and store the image URL on the `Movie` table.  Option 2 is to create a view in the database which handles the join.  Finally option 3 is to use EF 6 includes to prevent an N+1 query problem from lazy loading.

As long as `Movie` and `Image` are 2 different tables something will have to join the data.  If you are storing the image as a BLOB byte array you can use `.Select()` with an anonymous object to avoid pulling back the BLOB if you do not need it.  EF can be very efficient if you take the time to learn some of the inner workings and how it constructs the queries

Comment: Well, I don't need to do a join to access the Id of the image (since it is a foreign key on Movie). Isn't it possible to create an additional foreign property on Movie likewise (eg. Image_Url)?

Answer (score 0):

I assume a Movie has many Images, so every Image should have a foreign key to the Movie that it belongs to, something like MovieId.

Every Movie has zero or more Images. Therfore the Movie can't have a foreign key image_id: to which of its thousands of images should it point? So I assume that's a typo?

The reason that you are required to access your image table is because you didn't [configure your one-to-many](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) relation correctly. If you use the proper [Code-First conventions](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx), you wouldn't even need Attributes or Fluent Api. But even if you want unconventional column names you could use your queries without joins (however, internally entity framework will create the proper join)

The proper movie-has-many-images model would be:

```
class Movie
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    // a movie has zero or more images:
    public virtual ICollection<Image> Images {get; set;}

    ... // other properties
}
class Image
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    // every image belongs to exactly one movie using foreign key:
    public int MovieId {get; set;}
    public virtual Movie Movie {get; set;}      

    ... // other properties 
}
```

That's all! Entity framework knows that you plan to model a one-to-many relationship and create the proper tables, primary keys and foreign keys for you.

Besides your query would be easier:

> Don't think in Joins, think in collections you want to query!

"Give me all movies that starred Doris Day, with all images that were in the first five minutes:

```
var result = myDbContext.Movies
    .Where(movie => movie.Start == "Doris Day"
    .Select(movie => new
    {
        Title = movie.Title,
        First5Minutes = movie.Images
            .Where(image => image.StartTime < TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5))
            .Select(image => image.Url)
            .ToList(),
    }
```

Actually it probably won't work with TimeSpans, but you get the gist.

If you insist on naming your foreign keys `image_id` instead of the conventional ImageId, you should use fluent API or attributes to tell entity framework to create the required foreign key. See the one-to-many link above.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
In this case, Movie only has a single Image.
I don't need to do a join to access the Id of the image (since it is a foreign key on Movie). Isn't it possible to create an additional foreign property on Movie likewise (eg. ImageUrl)?

Comment: Nice of you to describe proper requirements. OK, apparently, a movie has only one image. Still: you don't specify whether this image belong to one movie? Is there a one-to-one or a one-to-many. Luckily you already googled on how to do one-to-one and one-to-many in entity framework. So what was it you don't understand?

Comment: Come on... I specifically wrote "one-to-many relation" in my original question.